# Custom image sizes for custom field media uploads

Tags: custom-field, uploads

Is it possible to resize my image uploads to different settings, depending on what custom field I'm on?

I'm using wpalchemy, and have an image uploader for a heap of different custom fields. It would be great if I could detect which custom field I'm currently on, and have different dimension options.

For example, if the custom field is my_special_image, I could stipulate 960x200px hard cropping, similar to featured posts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using WP's `add_image_size` function? Here's the [Codex entry.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

Basically you could add all the sizes you require throughout your theme via your functions.php and then call the appropriate size in your page/post template.

Good luck!

Comment: No offense, but IMO we don't *answer* to provide hints. I think *comments* are meant for that. I hope you understand.

Comment: John's answer, while not going into detail, does provide the base for what Michael needs. Don't go against someone just because they didn't provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your themes `functions.php` file underneath your existing image sizes:

```
add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );
```

Example:

```
add_image_size( 'home-bottom', 280, 150, TRUE );
```

Comment: An explanation _why_ and _how_ that solves the problem would be useful. :)